# How can I solve this if condition — I don't know where the problem is in this case?

Tags: c

```c
    float i, r1, r2, sum1, sum2; 
    char resistance[30];
    
    printf("what is the curent total: ");
    scanf("%f", &i);
     
    printf("what is the resistance1 and resistance2: ");
    scanf("%f%f", &r1, &r2);
    
    printf("what is the R you want to know there curren\n: ");
    printf("notes:write your choes in capital example R1,R2:");
    scanf("%s", resistance);
    
    sum1 = (r2 / r1 + r1) * i;
    sum2 = (r1 / r1 + r2) * i;
    
    if (strcmp(resistance, "R1") == 0) {
        printf("the current in this resistance is %f", sum1);
    } else if {
        printf("the current in this resistance is %f", sum2);
    }
```

Comment: Please use a more orthodox indentation style for C.
I strongly recommend either Allman (which is what I use, more or less)
or some version of 1TBS (which is used by many other people).
See Wikipedia on [Indentation
Style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) for information
about the variants.

The Pico style, especially with multiple `}` markers on a single line, is anathema in C.

Multiple close braces on a single line is a no-no;
multiple consecutive close braces at the same indent level is another.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages.  Doing a code dump without explaining what problem you're trying to solve is hopeless.  Your line of code `sum2 = (r1/r1+r2)*i;` is almost inevitably wrong — what's correct is less clear, not least because you've not explained what problem you're trying to solve.  You should check that the `scanf()` inputs worked.  You should limit the input to `resistance` using `%29s` so you don't get a buffer overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code fragment does not compile because there is an extra `if` after the `else`. You can test another condition in the `else` part with `else if (condition)` but this does not seem to be your intent.

Also note than the formulae are incorrect. Here is the math:

1. **V = i . R**
2. with **1 / R = 1/r1 + 1/r2**
3. and **V = i1 . r1 = i2 . r2**
4. replacing *R* in 1): **V = i . 1 / (1/r1 + 1/r2)**
5. replacing *V*: **i1 . r1 = i / (1/r1 + 1/r2)**
6. reducing to common denominator: **i1 . r1 = i / ((r2 + r1) / (r1 * r2))**
7. simplifying: **i1 . r1 = (i . r1 . r2) / (r2 + r1)**
8. dividing by *r1*: **i1 = (i . r2) / (r2 + r1)**
9. same for *i2*: **i2 = (i . r1) / (r2 + r1)**

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    float i, r1, r2, i1, i2; 
    char resistance[30];
    
    printf("what is the total current: ");
    if (scanf("%f", &i) != 1)
        return 1;
     
    printf("what are the resistance1 and resistance2: ");
    if (scanf("%f%f", &r1, &r2) != 2)
        return 1;
    
    printf("what is the R you want to know there current\n: ");
    printf("note: write your choice in capitals example R1,R2: ");
    if (scanf("%29s", resistance) != 1)
        return 1;
    
    i1 = i * r2 / (r1 + r2);
    i2 = i * r1 / (r1 + r2);
    
    if (strcmp(resistance, "R1") == 0) {
        printf("the current in resistance R1 is %f\n", i1);
    } else if (strcmp(resistance, "R2") == 0) {
        printf("the current in resistance R2 is %f\n", i2);
    } else {
        printf("choice must be R1 or R2\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: so it must be else not else if

Comment: @Ahmedhossvm: yes. As posted in the answer where you can see both possibilities

Comment: please can you tell me how can i write r1dividedr2+r1 all multiple* i how can i wite it in code equation the equation of sum1 and sum2

Comment: please can you tell me how can i write r1dividedr2+r1 all multiple* i how can i wite it in code equation the equation of sum1 and sum2

Comment: @Ahmedhossvm: the formulae are incorrect, I updated the answer with the math and correct expressions

Comment: thank you sir, its really help me a lot in my beginning journey in programming  ❤